# Why is declaring an array as an object correct in Java?

Tags: java

The following expression compiles:

```
Object oa = new float[20];
```

How is this expression valid?

As per my opinion, the correct syntax would be

```
Object [] oa = new float[20];
```

Comment: Arrays are Objects in Java.

Comment: 1. All arrays are objects. 2. Arrays of floats are *not* arrays of objects (so your "corrected" code will not compile)

Comment: How is this not a duplicate 6 years after Stack Overflow launched?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Arrays are objects in Java. So an array of floats is an object.

BTW, `Object o = new Object[20];` is also valid, since an array of objects is an object.

Also note that `Object[] oa = new float[20];` is invalid, since primitive floats are not objects, and an array of floats is thus not an array of objects. What would be correct is

```
Object[] oa = new Float[20];
```

Regarding arrays, since they are objects, they have all the methods of java.lang.Object. They also have a public final attribute `length`, and they are Cloneable and Serializable:

```
Object o = new float[20];
System.out.println("o instanceof Serializable = " + (o instanceof Serializable)); // true
System.out.println("o instanceof Cloneable = " + (o instanceof Cloneable)); // true
```

Comment: Is there any replacement to "Object" in the statement "Object oa = new float[20];"?   I understood your answer, but I am trying to mingle the line "Arrays are objects in java"

Comment: No, there isn't anything as generic as Object when it comes to primitives such as int, float, void, char...

Comment: Yes, there is. A float[] is of type float[], but also Object, Serializable and Cloneable.

Comment: @Chief Two Pencils: Thanks, now I understood from your comment that  "float[]" is replacement for "Object" and it solved my doubt

Comment: @RajeshKumar, glad it helped but I was kinda just proving a point. JB's is better in regards to your question.

Comment: @Chief Two Pencils: Yes I understood, I faced some page refresh problem , thanks all for helping me in getting answer...

Comment: `Object[] oa = new Float[20];` is allowed, but it's not correct.  This is a fairly big hole in Java's compile-time type checker, from the days before generics, and the consequence is a whole lot of runtime type checks.

Comment: Whoa, I thought I knew Java ;-)

Comment: then how should I add values to the array `Object oa = new float[20]; ` and iterate it.

Comment: If you need a variable of type float[], declare a variable of type float[], not a variable of type Object. Just because `Object oa = new float[20];` is valid Java and compiles fine doesn't mean that's how you should declare arrays.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, `Object` is a super class for all the objects in Java. So, making a reference of `Object` class and then using it as any other object is valid.

```
Object ob = new Integer(5);
```

Arrays in Java are nothing but the objects, so reference of `Object` class can be assigned an array.